# Shortcut Keys to Save As?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, save-as

Is there a shortcut key that will automatically "Save As" a file from a certain URL like below? I know <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> opens a file but I need a shortcut key that will "Save As" the file, and not "Save"

[image]

Comment: Unclear. Saving always in a particular folder can be Done in Settings (I assume Chrome?)

Comment: @harrymc Every time I save the same file name it adds a number at the end of the name, like (1) or (2) but I want to keep it the same name and replace is every time. That is why I need Save As

Comment: Is it always the same URL?

Comment: What OS are you using?  Have you looked at defining your own keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

Afraid not: The [Google list of Chrome shortcut keys](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) does not show what you want.